# How to show constraints of a maximization on a plot?

Tags: plotting, maximum

I have this function F:

```
l = 2.5;
n = 0.75;
U[z_, Wr_] := Piecewise[{{n*(z - Wr), 0 <= z - Wr}, {n*l*(z - Wr), z - Wr < 0}}]
WR = 10000;
F[x_, y_] := (x + U[x, WR]) + (y + U[y, x])
```

I used to find the Max point with:

```
Maximize[{F[x, y], x + y == 11000, 0 <= x <= 11000, 0 <= y <= 11000}, {x, y}]
{2562.5, {x -> 5500., y -> 5500.}}
```

then I used this to plot my function:

`Plot3D[F[x, y], {x, 0, 11000}, {y, 0, 11000}, PlotTheme -> "Web"]`

My question is How could show all of my constraints and my Max point on my plot.

```
x + y == 11000
0 <= x <= 11000
0 <= y <= 11000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
con = {x + y == 11000, 0 <= x <= 11000, 0 <= y <= 11000};

max = Maximize[{F[x, y], con}, {x, y}];

maxpos = {max[[2, 1, 2]], max[[2, 2, 2]], max[[1]]}
```

> {5500., 5500., 2562.5}

```
Legended[
 Show[
  Plot3D[F[x, y], {x, 0, 11000}, {y, 0, 11000}, PlotTheme -> "Web"],
  Graphics3D[{PointSize@0.05, Point@maxpos}]],
 con]
```

[image]